# Receive messages from IBM Websphere MQ using MQseries adapter in BizTalk 2016

Tags: biztalk, msmq, biztalk-2016

I need to connect to IBM WebSphere MQ using BizTalk 2016.

Can this be done using out of the box MQSeries Adapter? Do we need anything else to get this working (For example IBM Websphere MQ client) or only out of the box MQSeries Adapter is enough?

I have read some document that we have to install the Adapter for WebSphere MQ which ships with HIS. Why do we need this?

If this can be achieved with both out of the box MQSeries Adapter and Adapter for WebSphere MQ which ships with HIS then what's the advantage or disadvantage of one with others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBM MQSeries product has been discontinued by IBM. MQSeries adapter in BizTalk is meant for MQSeries specifically. If you are looking to connect to IBM MQ recent versions, you need to install HIS. This gives you MQSC adapter and support for latest MQ version. With latest HIS, you have option to use IBM MQ client or Microsoft Client (built into HIS) to connect to IBM MQ.

[IBM MQ, WebSphere MQ, and MQSeries product READMEs](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27006097)